# How to get zip code data with acs (American Community Servey) and rStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, data-science, feature-engineering

I am working on a class assignment using rStudio, acs package, and a data set.  I need to get city zip codes, and graph how many drug overdoses there were per zip.  However, I only have minimal experience with R, and I've never used it to do this before.  The "how to with R" information out on the web isn't very good, and most recommend using packages other than acs.  I've tried several acs functions, but I'm pretty sure I'm doing it wrong.

```
#Code so far:
install.packages("acs", clean = T)
api.key.install()
acs.tables.install()
library(acs)

zips = geo.make(state = "Illinois", key = "Chicago", zip.code = "*")
```

This code is supposed to return all zip codes for chicago.  It runs, but the variable "zips" doesn't seem to hold any data.  Can anybody help me out?

Thanks

P.S.

I've been trying to find an R/python data science tutor.  However, most sites and tutors I've tried are either really expensive or just interested in selling me the homework.  I am genuinely interested in learning data science, data mining, AI, etc..., and not just getting a grade.  So, if anyone knows of some good tutoring resources or would like to tutor, please let me know.  I trying to find someone for about $20.0/hr.  I know this is low, but please keep in mind I'm a currently unemployed college student; be merciful ;).

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You should subscribe and get an API key from [API key request](https://api.census.gov/data/key_signup.html)

```
  api.key.install("YOUR KEY") # only need to do once
```